# Can't change table reference format

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing

I need to change reference to table to "табл. CHAPTER_NUM.TABLE_NUM", I was tried to do something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ukrainian, utf8, 14pt]{extreport}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@table{табл. \thechapter.\arabic{table}\expandafter\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}
Lorem ispum \ref{t:table}.

\begin{table}
  \label{t:table}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{Col} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2.2cm}|}{Lorem} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2.2cm}|}{Ispum} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2.2cm}|}{Dolor} \\ \hline 
1  & 50 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\ \hline 
2 & 50 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\ \hline 
3 & 51 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\ \hline 
4  & 45 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\ \hline 
5 & 53 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\ \hline 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

it works perfectly with figures, but with tables it doesn't do anything.

Maybe is there any other way to change `\ref` format?

**P.S I'm using XeTex.**

Comment: Can you please show us a [minimal working exxample](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) to better understand what you are trying to do? I am confused by the current code snippet.

Comment: Did you think of using the `\cref` command, from `\cleveref`? This package is done for that.

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: @Johannes_B XeTex

Comment: I expected something like `ukranian` or `serbian` or another language spoken by humans, but ok :-)

Comment: By the way, a completely different thing. That thing you are referencing is not the number of the table, but the number of the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `\caption` before `\label{t:table}`, therefore the label is referencing the previous section.

Example file with some other suggestions and some simplifications:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}% a5paper to get a smaller image for TeX.SX
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@table{Table.\@ }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}
Lorem ispum \ref{t:table}.

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table caption}
  \label{t:table}
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format=1.0]
    S[table-format=2.0]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
  }
    \toprule
    {Col} & {Lorem} & {Ipsum} & {Dolor} \\
    \midrule
    1  & 50 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\
    2 & 50 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\
    3 & 51 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\
    4  & 45 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\
    5 & 53 & 1,44 & 1,85 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]